# Question about the thought process at multivariable limit calculation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Is the following calculation correct, using the substitution method?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{{x^2 - y^2}}{{2x + y}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{{x(1 - y/x)}}{{2 + y/x}} = \lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\frac{{1 - (y/x)^2}}{{2 + y/x}} \cdot \lim_{x\to0} x,$$ where $u = y/x \to 1/2 \cdot 0 = 0$.

I'd like to know, firstly if this is correct, and after that if there is other way to solve problems like this, thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over $\frac y x$ so your answer is wrong.

The expression is not defined along that lime $y=-2x$ so the limit is not even well defined.

Also along the  sequence $(\frac 1  n, \frac 1 {n^{2}}-\frac 2 n)$ you get a non-zero limit.

Comment: Then what am I supposed to do in cases like this?

Comment: @samivagyok The limit does not exist even if you exclude points with $y=-2x$. You have to find  sequence approaching $(0,0)$ along which you get a limit other than $0$.

Comment: Sorry, does it change anything, that I have to find the global limit for the function?

Comment: @samivagyok Global limit cannot exist unless limit along every line and every curve through the origin exists and all the limits are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking how to solve problems like this, I add this answer.

Look carefully at the denominator: For $y=-2x$ it is not defined while for $x\neq 0$ the numerator $x^2-y^2 = x^2-(-2x)^2 = -3x^2\neq 0$.

This suggests that if you move to $(0,0)$ along a curve close t0 $y=-2x$, you may push the value of the expression $\frac{{x^2 - y^2}}{{2x + y}}$ to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Now you choose curves close to $y=-2x$. Often the following trick works quite well: Add a power $x^t$ for $t>0$. With $t$ you can control how fast you get closer to $y=-2x$ while approaching $(0,0)$:

$$y=-2x+x^t \Rightarrow \frac{{x^2 - y^2}}{{2x + y}} = \frac{x^2-(-2x+x^t)^2}{x^t}\stackrel{expanding}{=} -3\frac{x^2}{x^t}-\underbrace{x^t+4x}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0}$$

Now, you see if you choose, for example, $t=4$, the limit for $x\to 0$ would be $-\infty$. If you choose, for example, $t=2$, the limit would be $-3$.

So, the limit you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, that was pretty eye-opening, and will surely be useful in the future!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)